# Rspec testing autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

i need to test autocomplete action in my controller. My test just need to expect count returned, but i cannot figure out how to do this.

Here is the method itself:

```
def autocomplete
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        model_suggestions = Vehicle.select([:model, :make]).where('make IS NOT NULL AND model IS NOT NULL').reorder('').order("make ASC, model ASC")

        if params.has_key? :model
          model_suggestions = model_suggestions.group(:model)
        else
          model_suggestions = model_suggestions.group(:make)
        end

        unless params[:model].blank?
          model_suggestions = model_suggestions.where('model LIKE ?', "%#{params[:model]}%")
        end

        unless params[:make].blank?
          model_suggestions = model_suggestions.where('make LIKE ?', "%#{params[:make]}%")
        end

        model_list = {model: [], make: []}

        model_suggestions.each do |car|
          model_list[:make] << car[:make].strip
          model_list[:model] << car[:model].strip
        end

        model_list[:make].uniq!
        model_list[:model].uniq!

        render json: model_list
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the routes:

```
get :autocomplete, constraints: {format: 'json'}
```

And here is the rspec test i need. I cannot think of anything. i am very new to rails and TDD. So please dont judge me so harsh

```
describe "GET #autocomplete" do
    before do
      FactoryGirl.create(:vehicle, make: "AUDI", model: "A4")
      FactoryGirl.create(:vehicle, make: "BMW", model: "M5")
      FactoryGirl.create(:vehicle, make: "BMW", model: "M3")
    end

    it "responds to with 2 makers" do
      get :autocomplete, :format => :json #giving param make: "BMW"
      # expect count 2 
    end

  end
```

How could i accomplish this??? Big thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could inspect the response's body:

```
it "responds to with 2 makers" do
  get :autocomplete, :format => :json #giving param make: "BMW"
  res = JSON.parse(response.body)
  # assertions on res
end
```

If you do this a lot, consider adding helper methods or something similar to stay DRY.

Comment: Thank soo much, i think few hours have been saved here :)